# PHP resize two arrays to the same size

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays of different or unknown sizes.
I want the larger one to be resized to the size of the smaller one by removing the last elements.

```
$array1 = array (1, 2, "dog", "cat");

$array2 = array ("house", 56);
```

$array1 has to be resized to match $array2 to get

```
$array1 = array (1, 2);
```

thank you

Comment: Please note that "I want" is not a question. You are expected to make an effort on your own and present the point where you got stuck or encountered an error you couldn't figure out yourself. There are several ways to achieve this if you take a look at [array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_slice` to reduce the size of an array:

```
$array1 = array (1, 2, "dog", "cat");
$array2 = array ("house", 56);

$size = min(count($array1), count($array2));
$array1 = array_slice($array1, 0, $size);
$array2 = array_slice($array2, 0, $size);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help (works both ways), I slightly changed your arrays:
EDIT: Edited based on @Thomas Sablik suggestion

```
<?php

$array2 = array ("house", 2, "dog", "cat");
$array1 = array (1, 56);

$countArray1 = count($array1);
$countArray2 = count($array2);

$finalCount = min(count($array1), count($array2); 
$arrayToCountDown = $countArray1 < $countArray2 ? $array2 : $array1;   

for($i = 0; $i < $finalCount; $i++) {
    $finalArray[] = $arrayToCountDown[$i];
}
print("<pre>".print_r($finalArray,true)."</pre>");
?>
```

The print is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => house
    [1] => 2
)
```

With array values like:

```
$array2 = array (3, 2, 8);

$array1 = array (56,"house","test", 59);
```

The print will look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 56
    [1] => house
    [2] => test
)
```

Basically, I count values in array, and than loop over larger one as many times as there are values in smaller one, and assing into new array.

Comment: thanks for your help but there nothing easier in PHP ?

Comment: You can use `$finalCount = min($countArray1, $countArray2); $arrayToCountDown = $countArray1 < $countArray2 ? $array2 : $array1;` to reduce most of the code. https://wandbox.org/permlink/PqE5Mtm3qhUzmXNH

Comment: @ThomasSablik thx for suggestion :) cirke, try now, should be shorter and simpler

Comment: Why do you need `$arrayCountDiff = $countArray1 - $countArray2;`?

Comment: I dont :). Leftover from editing...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a59cdded07993038ec9576f1742d8b2633032303

```php
$array1 = array (1, 2, 'dog', 'cat');
 
$array2 = array ('house', 56);

if(count($array2)<count($array1)) {
    for ($i = count($array2); $i <= count($array1); $i++) {
       unset($array1[$i]);
    }
    
    $array1 = array_values($array1);
} else {
    for ($i = count($array1); $i <= count($array2); $i++) {
       unset($array2[$i]);
    }
    
    $array2 = array_values($array2);
}

var_dump($array1);
var_dump($array2);
```

Loop through the extra elements and remove them using `unset`.

Comment: What if second array is bigger?

Comment: @JureW then the starting value of `$i` will not be `<= count($array1)`, so the for loop won't run.

Comment: OP wants _"the larger one to be resized to the size of the smaller one"_ Your code doesn't work if `$array1` is smaller than `$array2`.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I've updated the answer to modify either array.

Answer (score -2):

Here is code for resize $array2 to the number element as $array1

```
array_slice($array1, 0, count($array2))
```

Thanks

Comment: What if array2 is bigger than array1? As per OP: ..I want the larger one to be resized to the size of the smaller..